# What is important to know in regards to trig functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I believe I forgot everything I learned in pre calculus 3 years ago, and I need to fine tune my studies. I just took a look at the book I will be using this spring and it has a few questions stating $\cos 0 = 1$. Can some one tell me what that means, and direct me as what I should re-study?

Only trigonometric functions, i.e. cosine = 1/secant

or the unit circle.

What is imporatnt to know in regards to trig functions?

Comment: Review in detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions (also see Unit Circle graphic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll see if I can explain this without a picture, but I recommend first going back and reviewing the relationship between the trig functions and right triangles.

On any circle in the plane centered at the origin with radius $r>0$, then given some angle $\theta$ (where $\theta$ is always the angle formed between the positive portion of the $x$-axis and any ray that begins at the origin) the cartesian coordinate corresponding to the pair $(r,\theta)$ is $$(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))$$ Which is to say that $r\cos(\theta)$ is your $x$-coordinate and $r\sin(\theta)$ is your $y$-coordinate. Now if you choose an angle of $\theta = 0$, that is tantamount to saying you are interested in the cartesian coordinate in the plane that lies strictly on the $x$-axis. Again, the radius of our circle is $r$, so the circle cross the $x$-axis at $x=r$. This means we get the set of equations $$r\sin(0)=0 \quad r\cos(0) = r$$ This is enough to do deduce that $\sin(0) = 0$ and $\cos(0) = \frac{r}{r} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

> *"In mathematics, the trigonometric functions (also called the circular
>   functions) are functions of an angle."* ~ [Wikipedia page on Trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)

The first thing most people are taught, before being introduced to the unit circle is how to directly apply the trigonometric functions to a right-angled triangle (soon to be related to the unit circle). Here we have such an example of a triangle.
[image: Right-angled triangle]

Following this, we have the definitions of:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin \theta &= \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \\
\cos \theta &= \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \\
\tan \theta &= \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} &= \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}
\end{align}
$$

If you struggle to remember these definitions, you can always remember the phrase *SOH CAH TOA* which demonstrates how $\sin$, 'S', is *opposite*, 'O', over *hypotenuse*, 'H', and so on...

Here we have the unit circle as found on wikipedia, showing the definitions of all the functions. 
[image: Wikipedia unit circle]

The unit circle is a circle (go figure) with a radius of 1; this is what all the trigonometric functions are based on. The angle $\theta$ describes the rotation around the origin. As we can see from this circle, the $\sin$ function represents the vertical quantity and the $\cos$ function represents the horizontal quantity.

In your question to asked why $\cos 0 = 1$, we can see why in this picture. When $\theta$ is equal to 0, the *cosine* will be from the origin to the right side of the circle. This is the radius and as mentioned earlier; the radius of the unit circle is just that, one unit, 1. You answer.

Of course all of this is easily read over on the [Wikipedia page about Trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions), these are just some simplifications to get you started again.

Your question about what is important to know about the trigonometric functions, does depend on what you are looking to use them for. If you are just solving the functions depending on certain angles; it is important to know, as well as the definition of [the Radian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), the *'exact'* values. This would involve knowing such values such as $\sin \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Should you need to solve algebraic equations with trigonometric functions and solve *'proofs'* it would be good to know some trigonometric identities, like such:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Pythagorean Identities} \\
\cos^2x + \sin^2x &= 1 \\
1 + \tan^2x &= \sec^2x \\
1 + \cot^2x &= \csc^2x \\
\\
\text{Double Angle Formulas} \\
\sin {2x} &= 2 \sin x \cos x \\
\cos {2x} &= \cos^2x - \sin^2x \\&= 2\cos^2x - 1 \\&= 1 - 2\sin^2x \\
\tan {2x} &= \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2x} \\
\\
\text{Co-Function Identities} \\
\sin \left({\frac{\pi}{2} - x}\right) &= \cos x \\
\cos \left({\frac{\pi}{2} - x}\right) &= \sin x \\
\tan \left({\frac{\pi}{2} - x}\right) &= \cot x \\
\csc \left({\frac{\pi}{2} - x}\right) &= \sec x \\
\sec \left({\frac{\pi}{2} - x}\right) &= \csc x \\
\cot \left({\frac{\pi}{2} - x}\right) &= \tan x \\
\end{align}
$$

There are quite a few more of these, and they do come in handy a *lot* more than you might think. I got these ones from [An online table of them](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html).

In conclusion, read the wikipedia article first to make sure you understand the basics at least. Then decide where you want to go with trigonometry and see what is involved there. Generally fields correspond so you might end up needing a lot.

All the best for you in your en devour re-learning